# Curve fitting to a Planck's Curve

Tags: rows, curve-fitting

So I am aiming to fit my own data points to a blackbody curve, however am having difficulties.

The outline of what I am doing is on

http://python4esac.github.io/fitting/example_blackbody.html

But they use random data, I am trying to use my own CSV data.

This data is:

```
Wavelength
0.7,
0.865,
1.24,
1.61,
3.7,
4.05,

Radiance
0,
0.106718,
0.227031,
0.373527,
0.240927,
0.293215,
```

Is there anyway to get Python to go into the file and use these two columns instead? Everything I have tried so far has failed.

my code is as follows

```
import csv
with open('PythonCode1.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:

        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pylab as plt
from pylab import plotfile, show, gca
fid=open('PythonCode1.csv','r')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook        
def blackbody_lam(lam, T):
    """ Blackbody as a function of wavelength (um) and temperature (K).

    """
    from scipy.constants import h,k,c
    lam = 1e-6 * lam # convert to metres
    return 2*h*c**2 / (lam**5 * (np.exp(h*c / (lam*k*T)) - 1))

    wa = np.linspace(0.1, 6, 100)   # wavelengths in um
T1 = 1000.
T2 = 2500.
y1 = blackbody_lam(wa, T1)
y2 = blackbody_lam(wa, T2)
ytot = y1 + y2

sigma = np.ones(len(wa)) * 1 * np.median(ytot)
ydata = ytot + csv.row[1].randn(len(wa)) * sigma


and returns

%run "d:\temp\k1339544\tmpskczzu.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
R:\Canpy103.001\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.0.3.1262.win-x86\lib\site-    packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

 d:\temp\k1339544\tmpskczzu.py in <module>()
     27 
     28 sigma = np.ones(len(wa)) * 1 * np.median(ytot)
---> 29 ydata = ytot + csv.rows[1].randn(len(wa)) * sigma
     30 
     31 # plot the input model and synthetic data

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rows'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `wa` and `ydata` to artificial data, as was done in the example, you want to provide your own data.

If you format your data as two columns:

```
Wavelength,Radiance
0.7,0
0.865,0.106718
1.24,0.227031
1.61,0.373527
3.7,0.240927
4.05,0.293215
```

then you can ingest it with

```
data = np.loadtxt("PythonCode1.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
wa = data[:,0]
ydata = data[:,1]
```

This won't guarantee that the function can fit your data (it can't, the blackbody function lacks an adjustable scale parameter) or that the fit will converge, but this is the simplest way to get the data in.

Comment: That's great thanks! I understand that this should work, but Python keeps coming back with 

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension 

I have checked that the columns are equal in length but still no idea what  python is trying to get me to change.

Comment: Which line gives you the ValueError, and are you sure that `wa.shape == ydata.shape` ?